# What program should I use to draw pixelated retro-style graphics?

Tags: software-recommendation, pixel-art

I want to create a Pacman clone and I need to draw by myself the game's graphics (pacman, the ghosts, fruits ,etc.).

I'm looking for a drawing program to draw it like the original ones, with those big pixels. I'm looking for a program to draw squares to create the graphics.

Which program can I use to draw them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drawing with pixels requires a raster image editor, such as Photoshop, GIMP, MS Paint, Paint(dot)Net, etc, etc.  Almost any one will do. Use a tiny 1px pencil/brush - and zoom in until you can see the pixels!

If you are looking for tutorials, google this "Draw pixel art [insert name of software]".

Comment: Make sure to take off Anti-Aliasing with the tool if it has it on by default in the application you choose.

Comment: Also, NEVER save your pixel art as JPEG, because it's a lossy format designed for photographs, and as a result of compression you will end up with a noisy image and loss of detail. Instead, save as PNG.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of zooming i would prefer to switch to grids and apply snap to grid on illustrator. Use pen tool to draw individual elements. It is time consuming but it will give really nice images.

Answer (score 1):

Any program which allows you to zoom into the canvas far enough to see individual pixels and offers either a binary brush or an option to turn the hardness of your brush up to the point of having no anti-aliasing is good enough - Photoshop, GIMP, heck maybe even MSPaint.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I like BobSprite for pixel art: [www.bobsprite.com](http://www.bobsprite.com)

You need not to install.

And has nothing to pay.

You just use it!

It is easy but also is a complex, robust tool.

***I am affiliated with this tool.***